# Flip automorphism for a $II_1$ factor is not inner

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is known that for a $II_1$ factor $M$, the flip automorphism defined on $M \overline{\otimes} M$ by $a \otimes b \mapsto b \otimes a$ is not inner. A proof can be found on Vol. IV of the books by Kadison & Ringrose. I just found that in
[this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115875/which-von-neumann-algebras-have-inner-permutation-of-tensor-factors) the accepted answer by Jesse Peterson had provided a simple proof for this result. However I don't understand why the inequalities in the inner product calculations are true. Could someone provide a more detailed explanation? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key inequality is $|\tau(x)|\leq\tau(|x|)$. I cannot really follow what Jesse is doing in his first inequality, but all we need to do it take the triangle inequality to get a sum of terms
$$
|(\tau\otimes\tau)((p_k\otimes1)(v^*\otimes w^*)U(p_k\otimes 1))|.
$$
Then, with $x=(p_k\otimes1)(v^*\otimes w^*)U(p_k\otimes 1)$,
\begin{align}
x^*x&=(p_k\otimes1)U^*(v\otimes w)(p_k\otimes1)(v^*\otimes w^*)U(p_k\otimes 1)
=(p_k\otimes 1)U^*(vp_kv^*\otimes1)U(p_k\otimes1)\\
&=p_k\otimes vp_kv^*.
\end{align}
As this is a projection, $|x|=(x^*x)^{1/2}=x^*x=p_k\otimes vp_kv^*$. So
\begin{align}
|(\tau\otimes\tau)((p_k\otimes1)(v^*\otimes w^*)U(p_k\otimes 1))|
&=|(\tau\otimes\tau)(x)|\leq(\tau\otimes\tau)(|x|)=(\tau\otimes\tau)(p_k\otimes vp_kv^*)\\ &=\tau(p_k)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: The first inequality in Jesse's post is just the triangle inequality and some rearranging (just write down the argument of the trace explicitely). The second inequality is exactly your argument together with the fact that $|ux|=|x|$ for $u$ unitary.